# Finding the index of an item in a Vector in Julia

Tags: julia

If I have a Vector of Strings such as:
`["big", "friendly", "giant"]`, how can I get the index of `"friendly"` (2)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`findfirst`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findfirst-Tuple%7BFunction,Any%7D) function (and its friends [`findlast`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.findlast-Tuple%7BAny%7D), `findnext`, `findprev` and `findall`) for problems like this.

```
julia> x = ["big", "friendly", "giant"]
julia> findfirst(item -> item == "friendly", x)
2
```

This uses an anonymous function `item -> item == "friendly"` which tests each item in the array. If the function returns `true` the index of that item is returned. You can write it slightly more concisely as

```
julia> findfirst(==("friendly"), x)
2
```

If the item isn't found, `nothing` is returned.

Comment: My preference is: `findfirst(x .== "friendly")` which might be even more concise.

Comment: But it is much slower and allocates memory (a temporary BitArray).